# Python: Threads stopping without any reason

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I am trying to make a hash breaking application that will check all the lines of one 
file with all the lines in the rockyou dictionary. While with pre-hashing the rock you 
i got the time of checking one hash down to a few seconds its still not enough. This is 
why i am moving my program to multithreading. But my threads stop without rising any exceptions.

```
import threading
import datetime

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    hash_list=0
    def file_len(fname):
        with open(fname) as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        return i + 1
    list_len=file_len("list.txt")

    def run(self):
        while ThreadClass.list_len>0:
            ThreadClass.list_len=ThreadClass.list_len-1
            print str(threading.current_thread())+":"+str(ThreadClass.list_len)
for i in range(20):
    try:
        t = ThreadClass()
        t.start()
    except:
        raise
```

Here is output:
[image: Afther that there is only one thread printing]
When i run it after some time there is only one thread reporting. Why?
Thanks for all help

EDIT: One of the threads rises a key error.I dont know what that is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As calculating hashes is a CPU bound problems, using multithreading won't help you in cPython [because of the GIL](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#threads).

If anything, you need to use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing). Using a [`Pool`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), your whole code could be reduced to something like:

```
import multiprocessing

def calculate(line):
    # ... calculate the hash ...
    return (line, 'calculated_result')

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

with open('input.txt') as inputfile:
    result = pool.map(calculate, inputfile)

print(result)
# compare results
```

---

As to your problem with the threads: You're concurrently accessing `ThreadClass.list_len` from multiple theads.
First you access it and compare it to 0. Then you access it again, decrease it and store it back, which is [not thread safe](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm)
And then you access it again when you print it. Between any of these operations, another thread could modify the value.

To show this, I've modified your code a little:

```
import threading
import datetime

lns = []
class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    hash_list=0
    list_len= 10000

    def run(self):
        while ThreadClass.list_len>0:
            ThreadClass.list_len=ThreadClass.list_len-1
            ln = ThreadClass.list_len        # copy for later use ...
            lns.append(ln)

threads = []
for i in range(20):
    t = ThreadClass()
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print len(lns), len(set(lns)), min(lns)
```

When I run this 10 times, what i get is:

```
13473 9999 -1
10000 10000 0
10000 10000 0
12778 10002 -2
10140 10000 0
10000 10000 0
15579 10000 -1
10866 9996 0
10000 10000 0
10164 9999 -1
```

So sometimes it seems to run ok, but others there are a lot of values that have been added multiple times, and list_len even manages to get negative.

If you disassemble the run method, you'll see this:

```
>>> dis.dis(ThreadClass.run)
 11           0 SETUP_LOOP              57 (to 60)
        >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ThreadClass)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (list_len)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             12 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       59

 12          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ThreadClass)
             21 LOAD_ATTR                1 (list_len)
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             27 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             28 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ThreadClass)
             31 STORE_ATTR               1 (list_len)

 13          34 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (ThreadClass)
             37 LOAD_ATTR                1 (list_len)
             40 STORE_FAST               1 (ln)

 14          43 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (lns)
             46 LOAD_ATTR                3 (append)
             49 LOAD_FAST                1 (ln)
             52 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             55 POP_TOP             
             56 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   59 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   60 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             63 RETURN_VALUE
```

Simplified you can say, between any of these lines another thread could run and modify something. To safely access a value from multiple threads, you need to synchronize the access.

For example using `threading.Lock` the code could be modified like this:

```
class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    # ...
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                # code accessing shared variables inside lock
                if ThreadClass.list_len <= 0:
                    return
                ThreadClass.list_len -= 1
                list_len = ThreadClass.list_len   # store for later use...
            # not accessing shared state, outside of lock
```

I'm not entirely sure that this is the cause of your problem, but it may be, specially if you're also reading from an input file in your run method.

Comment: I am not calculating hashes. I have two file one is of hashes i want to break and other is rock you hashed by sha1. What i am doing is looking for 2 hashes that are the same and then writing hash and the rock you line number for decryption later.

Comment: And list.txt is a file with hashes thats why i check how long it is. And then run threads until there are no more lines left(all lines where checked by function i will add later)

Comment: @RaslavM - I just wanted to give an example of how something like this could be approached. Of course the real implementation is up to you. The important thing ist: threading won't improve your performance.

Comment: yes it will if one thread can search for a hash in a file why cant 2 or 4 and performance is not my problem but threads stopping

Comment: and besides i never worked with threads and this will be a good time to. even if in the end my performance isnt that much better

Comment: Thanks so much! I dont have enough practice with threads to know that

Comment: Just to let you know i fixed the problem